# Local install / uninstall of PyQt (pip interface?)

Tags: python, pyqt, pip

The [installation instructions](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/installation.html) for PyQt say:

```
python configure-ng.py
make
make install
```

I usually work on a personal `virtualenv` environment, and `pip install -e <path_to_package_source_folder>` allows me to install Python packages from source in a manner that allows me later to uninstall the package with `pip uninstall <name_of_package>`.

However, for PyQt, If I try:

```
python configure-ng.py
pip install -e .
```

it complains with `No setup.py found`.
Is there a way to build PyQt in a manner that allows for easy uninstall it later? (e.g. this could happen because that there is a new version of PyQt and I would like to upgrade to it)

Answer (score 0):

Try to provide the [`-destdir`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/installation.html#cmdoption-configure-ng.py--destdir) argument (see the notes about `PYTHONPAT`), that should do the trick. I doubt PyQt4 supports installation via pip/setuptools/distribute.

To uninstall it later it should be enough to delete the installed files.